# WSAConnectByName timeout

Tags: c, winapi, network-programming, winsock

I'm trying to use `WSAConnectByName()` to connect to an address.  However, it seems like it disregards the `timeout` parameter.

Here is the (only slightly modified) code from MS's example:

```
SOCKET ConnSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iResult;
BOOL bSuccess;
SOCKADDR_STORAGE LocalAddr = {0};
SOCKADDR_STORAGE RemoteAddr = {0};
DWORD dwLocalAddr = sizeof(LocalAddr);
DWORD dwRemoteAddr = sizeof(RemoteAddr);

ConnSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (ConnSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
    wprintf(L"socket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

bSuccess = WSAConnectByName(ConnSocket, NodeName, 
        PortName, &dwLocalAddr,
        (SOCKADDR*)&LocalAddr,
        &dwRemoteAddr,
        (SOCKADDR*)&RemoteAddr,
        (struct timeval *)&tv,
        NULL);
if (!bSuccess){
    wprintf(L"WsaConnectByName failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnSocket);
    return INVALID_SOCKET;       
}
```

When I use an address that doesn't exist (like a local IP address), instead of failing with a timeout, the code stops until some other timeout occurs.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to bad documentation.

The `timeout` parameter is only *partially used*. [`WSAConnectByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741557(v=vs.85).aspx) is a complex function, which performs many operations internally.

At the beginning exists code like this:

```
ULONG time, ms;
if (timeout)
{
  time = GetTickCount();
  ms = timeout->tv_sec * 1000 + timeout->tv_usec/1000;
}
```

and then several times it calls code like this:

```
if (timeout && GetTickCount() - time > ms) return WSAETIMEDOUT;
```

but the heart of the function calls to [`ConnectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606(v=vs.85).aspx) like this:

```
if (!ConnectEx(*))
{
  if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
  {
    WSAGetOverlappedResult(*); // you wait here and the timeout is not used!
  }
}
```

Both [`ConnectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606(v=vs.85).aspx) (which is an *asynchronous* function) and [`GetOverlappedResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209(v=vs.85).aspx) have no parameter for specifying a timeout. You end up waiting in [`GetOverlappedResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209(v=vs.85).aspx) after [`ConnectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606(v=vs.85).aspx) exits, but you can not set a timeout for it.

There exists only one nice solution - use [`ConnectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606(v=vs.85).aspx) directly and not use any timeouts.

else one problem point - [`GetAddrInfoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738518(v=vs.85).aspx) used to translate `nodename` to ip address. this function called with `timeout=0, lpOverlapped=0, lpCompletionRoutine = 0` - so here also can wait on DNS request. asynchronous query supported only begin from Windows 8

**EDIT**

if direct use [`ConnectEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606(v=vs.85).aspx) we can use timeout (thank [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) for idea) - create/use `OVERLAPPED.hEvent` and

```
OVERLAPPED Overlapped = {};
Overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0);
//... ConnectEx ...
ULONG NumberOfBytesTransferred = 0;
ULONG err = GetLastError();
if (err == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
{
    switch (WaitForSingleObject(Overlapped.hEvent, ms))
    {
    case STATUS_TIMEOUT:
        CancelIoEx((HANDLE)s, &Overlapped);
        err = WSAETIMEDOUT;
        break;
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        // really final NT status of operation is Internal and NumberOfBytesTransferred == InternalHigh
        // GetOverlappedResult set LastError by translating (NTSTATUS)Internal to win32 error
        // with the loss of accuracy, especially if  status > 0
        GetOverlappedResult((HANDLE)s, &Overlapped, &NumberOfBytesTransferred, TRUE);
        err = GetLastError();

        // code of GetOverlappedResult in this case for clarity
        //if ((NTSTATUS)Overlapped.InternalHigh == STATUS_PENDING)
        //{
        //  WaitForSingleObject(Overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE);
        //}
        //NumberOfBytesTransferred = (ULONG)Overlapped.InternalHigh;
        //if (0 > (NTSTATUS)Overlapped.Internal) 
        //{
        //  SetLastError(RtlNtStatusToDosError((NTSTATUS)Overlapped.Internal));
        //}

        break;
    default: __debugbreak();
    }
}
```

or for alternative use [`GetOverlappedResultEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448542(v=vs.85).aspx) with our timeout (but need windows 8+)

or the best choice (for my view) - use [`BindIoCompletionCallback((HANDLE)s,)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) or direct bind self IOCP for socket and not wait after call at all.

Comment: `ConnectEx()` uses standard overlapped I/O, so it is possible to use a timeout. You have to pass an `OVERLAPPED` structure to `ConnectEx()`, so provide it with a handle to an event object. Then you can call `WaitForSingleObject()` on that event before calling `GetOverlappedResult()`. If the event times out, cancel the `ConnectEx()` operation using `CancelIo/Ex()`.  If `WSAConnectByName()` does not already do that internally, I would suggest sending a feature request to M$ asking for it to be added.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, of course possible use timeout if direct yourself call `ConnectEx` - `WSAConnectByName` and create/use hEvent in `OVERLAPPED`. `GetOverlappedResult()` in this case - exactly wait on this event - so we can simply `WaitForSingleObject`(with our timeout) without then call `GetOverlappedResult()`. but i mean that the best solution (in my view) - use `ConnectEx` really asynchronously. direct bind IOCP to socket (or use `BindIoCompletionCallback`) and not wait at all. `ERROR_IO_PENDING` is ok. when operation finished - our callback called

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, i checked now on latest win 10 (1607) - still same code `ConnectEx(*)/if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)/GetOverlappedResult(*);`
`WSAGetOverlappedResult` - if be more exactly, but it does not change the essence of

Comment: "*yes, of course possible use timeout if direct yourself call `ConnectEx`*" - that is not what you said in your answer, though.  I suggest you clarify and expand the last sentence of your answer.

Comment: Sigh, ``WSAConnectByName()`` had such a promising documentation.

Comment: BTW, while I don't expect MS to change the way the function works internally (I suspect it will break programs that already use it), a rephrasing of the documentation is very much called for.

Comment: @nitzanms - i from self side always use asynchronous DNS query and  asynchronous ConnectEx with IOCP - and no problems with timeouts

Comment: @RbMm I'd consider using it, if I had some sources for understanding IOCP. As it stands, I only have Microsoft's documentation to work with.

Comment: @nitzanms - documentation of course exit ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx ) but i be say not complete enough. and can use IOCP direct (self-created IOCP, thread pool waited on it - better choice for servers) - and indirect, by BindIoCompletionCallback on socket handle (used system default pool and system created IOCP) - less code and more simply. good choice for clients

Comment: @RbMm - BindIoCompletionCallback looks promising, thanks. Do you have any suggestions for resources on this besides MS's documentation?

Comment: @nitzanms - https://young2code.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/iocp-with-the-original-or-old-thread-pool-api/

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in a worker thread.  The timeout only seems to apply if the connection actually times out (10060).  If the connection is refused (10061) the call may complete within a couple of seconds.  Likewise for other errors.  I have not experienced any hanging (running on Windows 10).

1 second may be a bit short for `WSAConnectByName`